# Problem to use add_action or remove_action

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I know the rule of add_action or remove_action like:

[image]

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'woocommerce_cross_sell_display', 10 );`

But how to apply remove_action this type of hook

[image]

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions', ' Points_Rewards_For_WooCommerce_Public–>mwb_wpr_woocommerce_cart_coupon', 10 );`

Its not working

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work. Have you tried ?

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions',  array( 'Points_Rewards_For_WooCommerce_Public', 'mwb_wpr_woocommerce_cart_coupon' ), 10 );
```

The syntax is like

```
remove_action( 'hook_name', array( 'class_name', 'callback_name' ), priority );
```

Comment: Where are you adding this remove_action ?

Comment: functions.php file in my child theme. by the way this hook come from a plugin name: Points and Rewards for WooCommerce - By MakeWebBetter

Comment: I think there is priority issues. Probably you might be calling remove_action before the add_action is called. Are you adding this hook directly in functions.php or inside any other hook ?

Comment: I am adding this hook directly in functions.php. I am removing some woocommece pluging hook in this way and work file but it's not working. I am trying to change priority from 10 to 100.

Comment: You need to check the Points and Rewards for WooCommerce plugin. The add_action hook probably would be written inside a hook. Use that hook to write a callback function and inside that callback, you can write remove_action hook code